# Can Ubuntu use C and D partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning

From Ubuntu I can see C and D partitions of Windows and I can look, change, delete and create anything in those partitions. Because I have a small HDD on my laptop (120 GB) I would make Windows partitions bigger and use them as storage for anything like pictures or so.

Is there any danger or advice I should not do that, can anything go wrong with using those partitions from Ubuntu? So it is clean install I didn't do no sharing or permissions, it is just like that.

Comment: if you do, don't use hibernation on windows.

Comment: TL;dr, yes. If you start modifying windows system files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue that I can see is that NTFS support in Ubuntu is a little slow.  Reading and writing to these partitions might be slow, but this may depend on your hardware.

You should test the speed on your system to see if it's fast enough for you - compare it with the native ext4 partition of Ubuntu.

Comment: So beside potentially slower reading and writing speed I can normally store anything on D partition since Ubuntu can use NTFS... 

Reason I want to to that is I could access my college documents or anything else from both Windows and Ubuntu and it would be like 1 big partition for whatever needed.

Than you very much for help!!! @neon